# iterating over rows without causing chained assignment errors

Tags: pandas, dataframe, iteration, apply

I have some data which I want to run functions on depending on the "pass".
On the 1st pass, some will return a number > 0 and others will 0.
Then on each consecutive pass, I only wish to perform the functions on those with the value of 0.

My first thought was use the apply function, but this causes a problem when I do successive passes as I do not think there is a way to operate the function on rows with a condition.

My second thought was to use an iteration:

```
for I in range(len(df))
    df.iloc[i]['Column5'] = 'Value'
```

This also poses a problem in that I think I am assigning a value to a slice and not the original dataframe.
This issue also occurs with the iterrows operator.

what is the solution?

Comment: Sample data and expected output available ?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_value.html